# How to automatically increase the height of select2 input box (multiple)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have a select2 input box for multiselet option in which, user can select as many options as he wants, if the selected options are occupying more space than available width then I wanted to increase the height of the select box automatically (don't want scroll option, all options should be in viewable space) and get the remaining options in next line. Currently options are coming in the next line but the height of the select box is not increased.

[image]

If I remove the height property in the **.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple** class, it is working. But I want this height property to control the initial height of the select box.

Below is the initial select box height without heigh property in the **.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple** and the auto height works perfectly here.
[image]

[image]

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: text;
  height: 22px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rd62bhbm/

Comment: You need to add a minimal code so that we can give you a proper response. A http://jsfiddle.net/ will be even better.

Comment: Edited my question with jsfiddle link

Comment: Please review my answer if it helps you, if not, we will find another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add this CSS to `select2-selection--multiple` class:

```
.select2-selection--multiple{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

[***Updated Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/4cgavcu6/), *I hope it works for you, Thanks.*

Comment: How to sort the options in alphabetical order in the initial stage and after every select and unselect? I tried the following which did not work. sorter: function(data) {
        return data.sort();
    }

Comment: I am pulling my hairs when finally your solution worked! thanks +1

Comment: it is 2023 and why it is still not in default CSS is mystery :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height:22px` instead of `height:22px`

```
select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: text;
  min-height: 22px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that already, it did not work. Because it is changing the initial height of the select box. I want the initial height of the select box to be 22px to make it uniform with other form input fields.

Comment: `Because it is changing the initial height of the select box`. What is the value in height you want initially? Set that desired height as `min-height`.

Comment: I want it to be 22px and I have put this value for min-height, it is rendering as shown in the second picture but I want it to be rendered as shown in the first picture.

Comment: @user1614862 did you find a solution for the issue?