# Set initial select2 height but allow it to expand vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have a [`select2`](https://select2.github.io/) box that I want to allow to expand upward, e.g. `height: auto`, but I also want to set its initial height, e.g. `height: 34px`.

How can I accomplish this? If I try to set both of them, one overrides the other. I'm trying to have the box expand vertically as needed without adding a scrollbar.

I've looked at other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681206/how-to-automatically-increase-the-height-of-select2-input-box-multiple), but nowhere can I find how to allow the size to increase but start at an initial value. I've set a `min-height`, but `auto` doesn't shrink to fit mid-height — I'm not sure where it's getting the initial value, actually.

It seems like it's a problem exclusive to Select2. `height: auto`'s starting size should be `min-height`, right?

Comment: just two ideas: 1. could try to use the keyword `!important` to `min-height:34px;` or height:auto; 2. you could try to work with "%" instead of "px" to make sure the format stays the same.

Comment: Yeah, the styles are applying just fine. I seem to be running into a fundamental problem: you can't set the same CSS property twice, obviously. But I believe `height:auto` should set height to `min-height` initially, and it does not in this case. Maybe I'll have to set `height: 34px` then monitor the box with JavaScript/jQuery and expand as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `min-height: 34px;` with `height: auto;` should work.
Try running the code snippet (which reduces the size of the second div after 3 seconds).

```js
setTimeout(() => {
 $("#shrink").html("smaller text");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.select2{
 min-height: 34px;
 height: auto;

 background-color: rgba(0,100,0,1);
 margin: 5px;
 border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div id="shrink" class="select2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Another solution is using Flexbox with the `grow` and `shrink` properties.
In this case, you need to wrap your `.select2` into a wrapper div (the flex container) with at least `display : flex` and add a `shrink: 1;` and `grow: 1;` properties to the `.select2` classes (the flex items). These will act as a proportion to follow when things grow or shrink.
[See this code pen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/weNNLR)

```
.flex-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.select2{
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 34px;

  background-color: rgba(0,100,0,1);
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

**NB:** [A guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [Flexbox Playground](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv) are good resources to get up to speed with flexbox.