# select2 v.4 multiselect - how to set a "default" (min) height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have a multiselect on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cucmLykm/). It works just as I expect, with a box size that increases based on number of selections.

What I want however, is that the initial height of this box to be let's say 10 or 20 pixels; How do I achieve that?

This is my .select-selection--multiple css class I'm configuring based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681206/how-to-automatically-increase-the-height-of-select2-input-box-multiple). I tried setting both `min-height` as well as an inline declaration on the `<select>` element.

I saw that there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089073/set-initial-select2-height-but-allow-it-to-expand-vertically) but the select2 v4 environment seems a bit trickier [even for flexbox]

[This github issue about the problem](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4756) seems to make some sense (the height cannot go lower than 32 pixels without putting a display none on the select2-container) but still doesn't deliver enough help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via css.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thingkhu/cucmLykm/6/) out

```
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: does this work for you? I see that it completely disables the select2 behavior

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thingkhu/cucmLykm/6/).

Comment: the problem in the question [also in the github issue] is that I can't go below those 32 pixels in height. It's nice that it can be increased but I want to decrease the height

Comment: hmmmm... adding a 'theme' might help