# Auto increase and decrease height of multi-select multiple bootstrap select2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use a multi select with bootstrap 3 and select2 where users can choose the months of the year. If I were to select all the months in the year as you can see in the image the selections take up more space than the input.

Is it possible to auto increase and decrease the input height to match the selections?

I tried adding the css inline on the select with `height: auto` but that didn't work. Even specifying a height did not work either.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" id="scheduler_months" multiple style="width: 100%">
    <option selected value='1'><?=_("Janaury")?></option>
    <option value='2'><?=_("February")?></option>
    <option value='3'><?=_("March")?></option>
    <option value='4'><?=_("April")?></option>
    <option value='5'><?=_("May")?></option>
    <option value='6'><?=_("June")?></option>
    <option value='7'><?=_("July")?></option>
    <option value='8'><?=_("August")?></option>
    <option value='9'><?=_("September")?></option>
    <option value='10'><?=_("October")?></option>
    <option value='11'><?=_("November")?></option>
    <option value='12'><?=_("December")?></option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

Since I didn't realize that the `select2` was creating the issue I found my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681206/how-to-automatically-increase-the-height-of-select2-input-box-multiple) and simply used the following css to fix my issue.

```
.select2-selection--multiple{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

So now I get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Am using yii2 php web framework, Can you check this if it may Help, https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#google_vignette

```
<?php
        echo Select2::widget([
            'name' => 'field_name',
            'data' => ['2'=>'February', 
                '3'=>'March', '4'=>'April',  '5'=>'May',  '6'=>'June'],
            'theme' => Select2::THEME_MATERIAL,
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...', 'autocomplete' => 'off'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]);
?>
```